# SQL Group by ID/Quarter Issue

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find the overall product sales by month, (ID by the ProductKey)

I'm finding cases where it groups some 'productkeys' for a given month but not others

```
select distinct pkm.productkey, dateparts.month,year,dateparts.SalesAmount
from dateparts
inner join(
select distinct productkey, month, "salesamount"=sum(salesamount)
from dateparts
group by productkey,Month 
) pkm on pkm.ProductKey = dateparts.ProductKey 
and pkm.salesamount=dateparts.salesamount
order by pkm.productkey, dateparts.month,year  

Expected

PK      MM      YY              SALESAM
266     9       2011        183.9382
266     10      2011        183.9382
267     1       2012        1011.66


Actual

PK      MM      YY              SALESAM
266     9       2011        183.9382
266     10      2011        183.9382
267     1       2012        202.332
267     1       2012        809.328
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT is rarely never needed when GROUP BY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply do aggregation without `inner join` ?

```
select productkey, month, year, sum(SalesAmount)
from dateparts d 
group by productkey, month, year;
```

Your issue is probably with `ON` clause it should be mapped with `ProductKey` &  `month`, `year`. But it is really not necessary for your desired result.

Answer (score 2):

More than grouping, it would seem that you're also looking to `SUM` the data for the same `productkey`, `month` and `year` values.

Try the following code:

```
select productkey, month, year, SUM(SalesAmount)
  from dateparts
 group by productkey, month,year
 order by productkey, month,year
```

I hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with you join.

Can you try below-

```
select distinct pkm.productkey, dateparts.month,year,dateparts.SalesAmount
from dateparts
inner join(
select distinct productkey, month, sum(salesamount) as salesAmount1
from dateparts
group by productkey,Month 
) pkm on pkm.ProductKey = dateparts.ProductKey 
and pkm.salesamount1=dateparts.salesamount
order by pkm.productkey, dateparts.month,year
```